# Title tag in layout is not translated

Tags: magento2, layout, localisation, page-layouts

I don't know if this a bug, but title tag in layout is not translated.

For example,

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Forgot Your Password</title>
    </head>
    <body>....</body>
</page>
```

Can you confirm if this a bug or not?

Answer (score 5):

It still does not seem possible to set a title in the head section and translate it, but you could create a custom `customer_account_forgotpassword.xml` to fix the issue with this code

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Forgot Your Password</argument>
    </arguments>            
</referenceBlock>
```

From [Devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_act) :

> The `<action>` instruction is deprecated. If the method implementation allows, use the `<argument>` for `<block>` or `<referenceBlock>` to access the block public API.

Answer (score 3):

currently it still does not seem possible to set a title in the head section and translate it. There is still an open issue for this bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2951

you can actually execute the method setTitle via Layout or in code to set a translated title (like mentioned in the issue):

in Layout:

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <action method="setPageTitle">
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Dashboard</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

in code:

```
$this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Create New Customer Account'));
```

Comment: `The <action> instruction is deprecated. If the method implementation allows, use the <argument> for <block> or <referenceBlock> to access block public API.`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Factory class

```
/**
 * @var PageFactory
 */
protected $resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('My Title'));
    return $resultPage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento bug. Add a question mark to match the corresponding entry in your translation file.

<del>'Forgot Your Password'</del>
'Forgot Your Password?'

Comment: NO, this is wrong, thumb down, see my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/134903/23344

Answer (score 1):

In my case it worked just like that.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
<head>
    <title>Shared products</title>
</head>
<body>
    ...
```

translation csv file:

```
"Shared products","Translated title"
```

Flushed the cache and the translated title showed up immediately. Tested on Magento 2.2.0 in development mode.

Comment: NO, this is wrong, thumb down, see my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/134903/23344

Comment: This solution worked for me although the text wasn't in the generated output after running `bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o en_US.csv -m` so I had to manually add it (tested in 2.4.4).

Comment: works for me too  <head>
    <title>custom text </title>
</head> was translated  thank you

Answer (score 0):

Need add translate to your theme locale file in **i18n**.

Seeems bug is in main translate file,
where added -

*"Contact Us","Kontaktieren Sie uns",module,Magento_Contact*

so, will translated in **Magento_Contact** module.

But header with title - is **Magento_Theme** module :D

Easy fix - in your theme create directory i18n , file **de_DE.csv**
and put 
*"Contact Us","Kontaktieren Sie uns"*

after run 
*php bin/magento setup:upgrade* AND
*php bin/magento cache:flush*

Comment: This didn't work @Alex